# How do I show whether an asymmetric $2D$ random walk eventually returns to the origin or not?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $p,q$ be probabilities of taking $+1$ and $-1$ steps respectively along $y$-axis, while $r,s$ denote the probabilities of taking $+1$ and $-1$ steps respectively along $x$-axis. It is given that $p+q+r+s=1.$

I am trying to show whether the expected number of returns to origin is finite or infinite. Let $N$ be a random variable that counts the number of returns. Hence:

$EN=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(S_{2n}=0|S_0=0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{n}{k}^2(pq)^k(rs)^{n-k}$

Now by Stirling's approximation:

$EN\approx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2n)^{2n+\frac12}}{(n-k)^{2n-2k+1}(k)^{2k+1}}(pq)^k(rs)^{n-k}+(1-4pq)^{\frac{-1}{2}}+(1-4rs)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

How do I test for convergence of the above series?

Besides, is there a better approach to this problem, given that I am not really familiar with Markov chain?

Comment: If there is asymmetry in either the $x$ or $y$ axis then you can use the law of large numbers to claim our position on that axis goes to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ with prob 1, so we cannot return to the origin an infinite number of times.  So then the only remaining case is $p=q$ and $r=s$.

Comment: Are the movements only along the $x$ and $y$ axes or along directions parallel to these axes? For example, if we are at point (2,0), can we only go to (1,0) or (0,3) ("along the axis" as you have written) or can we also go to (2,1) and (2,-1)?

Comment: Bernard Masse, yes, movements are always parallel to the two axes. A diagonal move is not permissible.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the LLN approach was helpful. Intuitively it seems that the random walk is recurrent for $p=q$ and $r=s.$ Can you give some hints for proving this rigorously?